# Replicate stackoverflow's similar questions in PHP/MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

When you create a new question on stack, upon entering the title it gives you a list of "Questions that may already have your answer".

This is exactly what I need to do, but in PHP/MYSQL. The app will be scaled out to thousands so keep in mind it should be able to work on a large scale.

So for instance a user will be creating page's (like on facebook) when they enter the title of the page, I need something to search it against the database and return similar titles.

MYSQL LIKE won't work, it needs to be more advance than that. 
SOUNDEX seems to have a few people complaining about it, so not sure about that either.

In practice it would need to know the diffrence in '&' and 'and', ignore words like 'the' and punctuation along with small typo's.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Stack Overflow runs on ASP.NET and [uses the .NET Lucene port to handle full-text searches](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/). As far as I know, MySQL isn't exactly capable of handling that kind of queries.

Comment: @Dale If you wanted to have the same functionality in a PHP/MYSQL app how would you go about it?

Comment: @user1353059, IMO, that's a major engineering undertaking and you'll need to resolve many, many smaller subproblems. This almost certainly exceeds the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well, now there is a question.. Off the top of my head I would need a form, a database full of stuff to search for matches and a far superior knowledge of sql than I currently have. I would use jQuery for ajax handling, when a user types into the box I would fire off an ajax request containing the value typed, query the database with said value and return the first 10 matches, into some element (probably a div tag) located near the input field.

Comment: Meta have extensive list of Stackoverflow Clone in PHP: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Answer (score 0):

> >The app will be scaled out to thousands so keep in mind it should be able to work on a large scale.
>
> > in PHP/MYSQL

Divizion by zero :)

You have to use special software for such searches, like [SphinxSearch](http://sphinxsearch.com).

Regarding MySQL solution:

1. filter the string by removing trashy keywords and symbols
2. Use [full-text search functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use the fulltext search feature: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

For the client, I've used jQuery UI Autocomplete with great results: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/